# ¿Filtrar datos a tiempo real sin recargar página con query scope LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel, ajax, scope

estoy haciendo un buscador de artículos de equipos de computo, me sirve el buscador pero hace recarga de página, yo había hecho un anteriormente con AJAX pero, al usar ajax con laravel, en el momento de filtrar datos se colocaba muuy pesado y tardaba demasiado para filtrar un dato, en cambio, los query scopes son mas rapido y son funciones de laravel por lo que preferí usarlo, pero se me da duda por si se puede usar a tiempo real?

Dejo algo de los códigos:

**.-Controlador**

```
public function tabla_clientes(Request $request)
{
    $cliente = $request->input('cliente');

    $cliente = Cliente::select('*')
                ->cliente("%$cliente%")
                ->paginate(5);
    return view('sys.tablas.tabla_clientes')->with(compact('cliente'));
}
```

**.- Modelo**

```
public function  scopeCliente($query, $cliente)
{
    if ($cliente) {
        return $query->where('cedula', 'LIKE', "%$cliente%");
    }
}
```

**.-Vista**

```html
<table class="table table-borderless text-center">
      <thead class="card-header">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Cedula</th>
          <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
          <th scope="col">Dirección</th>
          <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
          <th scope="col">Fecha de registro</th>
          <th scope="col"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($cliente as $row)
      <tr>
       <td>{{ $row->cedula }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->nombres }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->direccion }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->telefono }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->fecha_clientes }}</td>
       <td>
        <a href="/edit_client" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
        <a href="/delete_client" class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
       </td>
      </tr>
     @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar `DataTable` aqui un ejemplo de lo que buscas https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Comment: Cuando ingresás por primera vez a es página, ya traes de la DB todos los clientes? O es justamente el método `tabla_clientes`? Si los traes todos, entonces te conviene filtrar directamente desde JS (podes usar DataTables como dice @anayarojo). Si no traes todos, entonces no te queda otra que utilizar AJAX. Ahora, AJAX y `query scopes` no tienen nada que ver, no se porque los comparás ni que habrás probado exactamente.